# Return duration from a function

Tags: javascript, vimeo, froogaloop, vimeo-player

One of the functions for the vimeo API (with froogaloop) is getDuration().

I am trying to make a function that will return the duration, but somehow I am getting Object as result. The Vimeo API documentation doesn't specify how are you supposed to do this.

I believe this is incorrect:

```
function getDuration() {
    return player.api('getDuration');
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeBwt/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`getDuration()`** accepts a callback function that gives you the duration of the media.

For example:

```
player.api('getDuration', function(dur) {
    alert(dur);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SeBwt/1/)**

Comment: Aha! But how do you return it from the callback ?

Comment: Since its an async call, it uses the callback mechanism. Maybe you should consider structuring your application around callbacks as well.