# Froogaloop get reference of event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, froogaloop

I am using the example presented in https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api:

Javascript + HTML:

script.js:

```js
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');

        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    function onPause(id) {
        status.text('paused');
    }

    function onFinish(id) {
        status.text('finished');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
        status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div>
  <button>Play</button>
  <button>Pause</button>
  <p>Status: <span class="status">&hellip;</span></p>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I want to be able, at some later time, to add instructions to an event.
Say, I want to add alert('123') to 'pause' event:

```
oldPauseEvent = player.get('pause'); //I made it up obviously..
player.addEvent('pause',newPuase);

function newPause(id){
    // do old stuff of 'pause' event. Namely onPause()
    oldPauseEvent();  
    // do new added stuff 
    alert('123');
}
```

I can't seem to be able to find where or how the events are stored in `player`. I couldn't find anything helpful in the API documentation in Viemo website.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the pause button. The Froogaloop api method getDuration() is returned as an alert.

**Useful links:**

[Return duration from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796875/return-duration-from-a-function/16796960#16796960)

[Further explanation of callback method](http://jsfiddle.net/SeBwt/3/)

[Method: seekTo, which does not have a return value](http://www.serkanyener.com/web-development/how-link-to-specific-parts-of-an-embedded-vimeo-video-using-froogaloop-api)

```js
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');
        
        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });
    // On pause button click, call getDuration().
    // Get Returned duration via _callback and alert it
    $('#pauseID').bind('click', function() {
        getDuration(function(duration) {
          alert('Video Duration: ' + duration);
        });
    });
    // Call the API when the pause button is pressed.
    // getDuration() is a froogaloop api method that has a return value.
    function getDuration(_callback) {
        player.api('getDuration', function(dur) {
           _callback(dur);
        });
    }  
    
    function onPause(id) {
        status.text('paused');
    }

    function onFinish(id) {
        status.text('finished');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
        status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div>
  <button>Play</button>
  <button id='pauseID'>Pause</button>
  <p>Status: <span class="status">&hellip;</span></p>
</div>
```